# Is there any consistent way to detect if a user is System Admin via Apex?

Tags: apex, profile, customsetting, system-admin

I am currently developing a managed app where I have a Visualforce Page that should that should be used only by the System Admins.

I wanted to know if there is any consistent way of figuring out if the current user is an Administrator or not, other than checking by the Profile with a hardcoded value like 'System Admin'.

**The workaround that I've thought so far is:**

After installation notify all users that the app/package was installed, and if you're a System Admin, you should go to the custom settings and define a hardcoded value for the Profile of the System Admin that you are using. If there are 2 system admins(*even though I wouldn't understand why would it be the case to have more than one*), one of them will do the work.

After that, I can succesfully detect if the user is a System Admin and I can let him do some "administrative" stuff relevant to the functioning of my app.

*Is there any other workaround that is more consistent and avoids this round trip of configurations?*

Comment: Idea is that System admin is only profile that has  ModifyAllData and AuthorApex permission and has been created in the same minute as environment has been created

Comment: I've never tested but If that and Admin A that was created at the moment in which the environment was created can create an Admin B. This Admin B, can deactivate Admin A, right? If yes, that logic would lead to an inactive user right?

Comment: That idea is about how to get admin profile. Then you just query active user with that profile id

Comment: Yepp... I sorted out that too. Please, formulate all that as an answer and I will recognize it as a valid one.